# When offering a list of examples that is 3-4 items long in parenthesis, how is it formatted?

Tags: grammaticality, latin, lists, example

When offering a list of examples, I've seen it done 4 different ways:

- (e.g., x, y, and z)
- (e.g., x, y, z)
- (x, y, and z)
- (x, y, z)

Which of these is correct? Are they all okay to use?

Example used as a sentence:

- Our website offers links to various resources across campus (e.g.,student services, campus housing, and parking services).
- Our website offers links to various resources across campus (e.g.,student services, campus housing, parking services).
- Our website offers links to various resources across campus (student services, campus housing, and parking services).
- Our website offers links to various resources across campus (student services, campus housing, parking services).

Comment: All but the last seem fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

I have two comments.

1. There is no need for a comma after 'e.g.' (in i and I), but there is a need for a space.
2. I don't like the 'and' in the list as it seems to finalize something that is only an example, but leaving it out seems ungrammatical. I would suggest a fifth option that overcomes this:

> (x, y, z etc.)

This also seems to me better for a website, going straight into the list instead of starting with 'e.g.'